# error TS2339: Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'DataSource<{ Cards: Card[]; }>

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo-server, typegraphql

I'm building a simple GraphQL API using typescript and I'm running into the error above and having issues resolving. The resolver is supposed to take in an argument so that users can look for a specific card from the API.

The error occurs on this resolver:

```
const cardResolver = (parent: void, args:Card, context:Context, info: void): Card[] | Card => {
const { cardName }: { cardName:string } = args; 
console.log("Context: ", context.dataSources.cards)
return context.dataSources.cards
    .filter((a:Card) => a.cardName == cardName)}
```

Here the rest of the code itself:

```
import { ApolloServer, gql } from 'apollo-server';
import { ApolloServerExpressConfig, Config } from 'apollo-server-express';
import { DataSources } from 'apollo-server-core/dist/graphqlOptions';

const typeDefs = gql`

    type Card {
        id: ID
        set: String
        cardName: String
        type: String
        rarity: String
        cardNumber: String
        initialRelease: String
    }

    type Query {
        cards: [Card]
        specificCard(cardName: String): Card
    }
`

interface Card {
    id: string, 
    set: string, 
    cardName: string, 
    type: string, 
    rarity: string,
    cardNUmber: string, 
    initialRelease: string 

}

//Test Data
const cards = [{
    id: "0001", 
    set: "Series 1", 
    cardName: "Ghoul Trooper", 
    type: "Skin", 
    rarity: "Epic",
    cardNUmber: "214", 
    initialRelease: "Season 1" 
    },
    {
    id: "0002", 
    set: "Series 1", 
    cardName: "Skull Trooper", 
    type: "Skin", 
    rarity: "Epic",
    cardNUmber: "214", 
    initialRelease: "Season 1" 
    }
]

interface Context {
    dataSources: DataSources<{Cards: Card[]| Card}>
}


const cardResolver = (parent: void, args:Card, context:Context, info: void): Card[] | Card => {
    const { cardName }: { cardName:string } = args; 
    console.log("Context: ", context.dataSources.cards)
    return context.dataSources.cards
        .filter((a:Card) => a.cardName == cardName);
        // https://www.apollographql.com/blog/graphql/filtering/how-to-search-and-filter-results-with-graphql/
}

const resolvers = { //do I strong type this?
    Query: {
        // initially got the idea to query items based on id from this page: https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#arguments
        cards: () => cards,
        specificCard: cardResolver
    },
};

const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers
})
server.listen({port:8000})
    .then((serverInfo) => console.log("Server running at ", serverInfo.url))
```

Thank you for any and all help, I've been banging my head against the wall on this one.

Comment: You may be missing a `dataSources` [property](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/data-sources/#adding-data-sources-to-apollo-server) in your ApolloServer definition. So underneath `resolvers` add a dataSources property whose value is a function and this function returns an object with a cards property whose value is your cards data.

Comment: with a c̶a̶r̶d̶s̶ specificCard property

Answer (score 0):

Kill/ close the server and re-run it the error will be gone.

for it worked just fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).